# How to allow boolean True on just one model in table in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-constraints

I've got a model where I would like there to be able to have one set as the 'app default'.

In this model I added a field named `is_app_default` in order to help accommodate this.

```
class TreeLevel(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    long_description = models.TextField()
    is_app_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tree Level"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tree Levels"

class Layer(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    tree_levels = models.ManyToManyField(TreeLevel)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Layer"
        verbose_name_plural = "Layers"
```

The `Layer` model links to `TreeLevel` with an m2m. Ultimately I would like the `is_app_default` `TreeLevel` automatically added to every `Layer` m2m relationship - which is why there can only be *one* `TreeLevel` with `is_app_default` set as True.

*My potential solution(s):*

Users with admin may be creating new `TreeLevel` objects - so I need to make sure they aren't setting that Boolean in any new models. I think I can override the `save()` method on `TreeLevel` to check the DB to see if another with that boolean as True exists - if so? Don't save the 'new' one and return an error. But I think this hits the database - causing unnecessary queries potentially?

Then additionally, I would also need to override the `save()` method on `Layer` and add the 'default' `TreeLevel` to that many2many at that time.

Is there a good way to 'automatically' handle this with these relationships?

*My ultimate goal:*

Have a default `TreeLevel` that is automatically added to every `Layer` many to many relationship whenever a `Layer` is created.

*Questions:*

Would my proposed solution work?

I've tried looking into [Djangos Unique Constraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint), but I think those are more on a row level, as opposed to a Table level.

Comment: The m2m between `TreeLevel` and `Layer` looks odd, why not use a `ForeignKey`, so a `TreeLevel` with an fk to `Layer`?

Comment: Because a `TreeLevel` may exist to multiple `Layer` objects.

Comment: and a `Layer` can have *multiple* `TreeLevel`s? I'm a bit confused what the modeling exactly means.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. A `Layer` can have *multiple* `TreeLevel`s and a `TreeLevel` can belong to multiple `Layer` objects.

Comment: `models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False` will keep Django_admin from setting this field`